# Проблема с открытием ключа реестра при автозапуске программы

Tags: delphi, реестр

У меня приложение запускается при старте ОС (*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432 Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersi on\Run*).

При создании формы запускаемого приложения

```
Const
  C_sidetrack_reestr = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  C_KeyRun = '\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run';

procedure TFMain.INITIALIZATION_REGISTRY;
//initialization
begin
  Pr_RegAutoRunBackup := TRegistry.Create;
  Pr_RegAutoRunBackup.RootKey := C_sidetrack_reestr;
  Pr_RegAutoRunBackup.OpenKey(C_KeyRun, True);
  if Pr_RegAutoRunBackup.OpenKey(C_KeyRun, True) then
    Prs := 'true'
  else Prs := 'false';
end;

procedure TFMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Prs := '';
//  sleep(10000);
  INITIALIZATION_REGISTRY;
…
End
```

Почему-то *Prs := **false***;

Хотя при обычном запуске, все нормально «Prs := **true**».
Я уже и «sleep(10000)» - не помогает, думал файл реестра, как-то частями читается…

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Под каким пользователем запускается приложение?

Comment: Админом (на ПК один пользователь)

Comment: UAC на компе включен?

Comment: Вам только почитать содержимое ключа нужно? Или вы туда что-то записывать хотите? Sleep вам здесь не поможет. И объект класса TRegistry вообще-то удалять за собой нужно.

Comment: "UAC на компе включен?" - нет

Comment: *"Вам только почитать содержимое ключа нужно? Или вы туда что-то записывать хотите?"* - да запись предполагается

Comment: А что значит "при обычном запуске"?

Comment: "обычный запуск", я имею ввиду запуск вручную, когда ОС загружена. На одном из сайтов, говорят: "Pr_RegAutoRunBackup := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);", Но это не совсем подходит, т.к. после этого я в реестр начинаю писать

Answer (score 2):

Причина в том, что Windows не запускает приложения из автостарта с повышенными привилегиями при отключенном UAC, даже если пользователь администратор. А для записи в раздел `HKLM` нужны эти самые привилегии. Почитать содержимое этого раздела можно и без привилегий, через метод `TRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly`. Возможно, для автозагрузки вас устроит раздел текущего пользователя `HKCU`, там таких ограничений на запись нет.

Если вам очень нужно использовать раздел `HKLM` и автоматический запуск программы, можно воспользоваться планировщиком заданий, создав задачу на запуск программы с повышенными привилегиями при входе пользователя в систему.